# can we have wireless active sync for getting mail in mobile from exhange server in brew?

Tags: brewmp

can we have wireless active sync for getting mail in mobile from exhange server in brew

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "Is it possible to write a software that communicates with an Exchange server" - yes, as BREW has a TCP/IP networking library.

If you mean "Where do I get an app for that", there are probably several options - I found [Remoba's RemoSync](http://www.remoba.com/remosync.html) which is available on Verizon in the US.